# PySpark IntelliJ IDE Interpreter

Tags: intellij-idea, pyspark

I am able to configure and run PySpark from IntelliJ by adding SPARK_HOME and PYTHONPATH to the Run time environment variable configuration. But I also want to use the interpreter to recognize PySpark and aid in development.

I am using the paid IntelliJ Ultimate Edition and have PyCharm (Python) installed via a plugin. I tried both on 2017.1 and 2018.1 installations.

[image]